# arc welder for line app 5.0.4

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-arc

I have been trying to use arc welder to run the line app 5.0.4 however, it can't seem to connect to line. The app launches but when you go to login it just keeps loading and does nothing. I have tried different verison of the line app and all do the same thing. Is there any way to address this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you the developer of "the line app 5.0.4"?

Comment: no. but it seems to be a simple connectivity issue. line app just won't connect to line

Answer (score 0):

After making sure every steps you performed well, I'd like to say ARC is in beta and not every app is supported. You could post it on [crbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) or report this to the CWS dev support team at https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/